# Daypilot control is freeware or not

Tags: asp.net, daypilot

I would like to know using daypilot control which control i should
able to use in my code.

I want to add dll's in my code if they available free.

please help me to identify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see [here at daypilot](http://www.daypilot.org/download.html) they clearly say it's open source so that means free, except for the pro version witch is commercial.